# how to get the repeater item count inside the gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am not sure if this possible. What I am trying to do is. I have a gridview inside the gridview item template i am populating the repeater.

I want to get the last row in the repeater so I can format the text properly.

So far I cannot get the repeater items count I try to use find control but i ended up in an error.

Me.Items.count is a different one.

```
          <asp:GridView ID="gvApprovalSetting" runat="server" CssClass="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" RowStyle-CssClass="column1" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="odd"
                CellPadding="4" GridLines="None">
                <RowStyle CssClass="column1"></RowStyle>
                <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approvers "  ItemStyle-Width="200px" HeaderStyle-Width="200px">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptApprovers" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <%-- <%# IIf(Container.ItemIndex = Me.Items.Count -1, Eval("DisplayName") & Container.ItemIndex , Eval("DisplayName") & ", " & Me.Items.Count) %>--%>
                                     <%# Container.ItemIndex%>
                                    <%--<%# Eval("DisplayName") & ", " %>--%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </ItemTemplate>                           
                    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

The Current Output is "User1,User2,User3," I want just to trim the comma in the end.

Regards to all

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following function

```
.TrimEnd(',')
```

Comment: I tried that but i ended up with the output of User1 User2 User3

Comment: @Mico can you put your data source code which you are using to bind the data.

Comment: I am populating the data inside the gridview row databound 
 rptApprovers.DataSource = datatable
 rptApprovers.DataBind()